# Automate GCP Service Account Creation

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible for my webapp to create service accounts on behalf of my users in their GCP?

Ideal flow would be:

1. Use performs Google OAuth via my webapp
2. Correct scopes are passed and permission is granted
3. My app receives the authority to create service accounts on behalf of user

Is this at all possible? I'm struggling to find an example or find the relevant scopes via Google Oauth that grant such permissions.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is very easy to create service accounts. There are many examples in Python, C#, Java, etc. on the Internet. The OAuth scope required is **cloud-platform**. The IAM identity requires an IAM role https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#service_account_permissions. However, there is a difference between creating a service account (first step) and create a service account **key** JSON file (second step). Note: Google Cloud has limits on the number of service accounts and keys. The default is 100 service accounts per project and 10 keys per service account.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley I made some progress from the time of posting the original request, and I'll share my work open source once it's good enough. :v:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @John Hanley  Yes, you can create service accounts.The OAuth scope required is cloud-platform.To create a service account, at minimum the user must be granted the Service Account Admin role (**roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin**) or the Editor basic role (**roles/editor**).

After you create a service account, you might need to wait for 60 seconds or more before you use the service account. If you try to use a service account immediately after you create it, and you receive an error, you can retry the request with [exponential backoff](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/retry-strategy).

By default, each project can have up to 100 service accounts that control access to your resources.

Checkout the [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts) on Creating and Managing Service Accounts.